# rearrange collectionViewCell once the scrolling to next item ends

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionView` and my `collectionViewCell` contains an `imageView`, so when I'm loading my view for the first time it seems fine, but when I scroll through it, it gets misplaced , see the images

i have 3 images in my collectionView cell the first image is at place but not the second and third images
before scrolling (image1)

[image]

after scrolling (image2) (when am horizontally switching to next image)

[image]

my `collectinView` supports Horizontal Scroll and (pink background) is my cell , (yellow background) is `CollectionView` as you can see once I scroll to next image my cell gets  a little out of screens, any idea how to fix this ???

my codes :

in `tableView`:

```
extension TableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return contentImages[collectionView.tag].count
    }


    func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }




    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",
                                                                         forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        //cell.imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, collectionView.frame.width, collectionView.frame.height)

        cell.imgViewOfCell.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit


        cell.imgViewOfCell.image = ResizeImage(UIImage(named: contentImages[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item])!, targetSize: CGSizeMake( cell.imgViewOfCell.frame.width ,  cell.imgViewOfCell.frame.height))
        //imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageModel[collectionView.tag][indexPath.item])

        return cell
    }

}
```

collectionViewCell :

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imgViewOfCell: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        imgViewOfCell.frame = self.bounds
        self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()

        }

}
```

in `tableViewCell`:

```
    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
    <D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>
    (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row
    collectionView.reloadData()
}


var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
    get {
        return collectionView.contentOffset.x
    }

    set {

        collectionView.contentOffset.x = newValue

    }
    }
```

Any idea of how to fix this? Please let me know what am doing wrong or what I'm missing.

Comment: It seems ok but its better for us if you compare your issue with same image in cell with and without scrolling

Comment: @JigarTarsariya please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

ended up with this ,after debugging i got to know  that  my Cell's `x` origin was not accurate , so am calculating this manually on my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this :

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",
                                                                     forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


    cell.imgViewOfCell.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        cell.frame.origin.x = 0
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {

        cell.frame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width

    }else if indexPath.row == 2 {

         cell.frame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.width*2)

    }else if indexPath.row == 3 {

        cell.frame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.width*3)
    } 
     ....... }
```